# How to set image metadata with python API 0.11.0 in openstack grizzly?

Tags: python, openstack

I work with a [DevStack](http://devstack.org/)-Grizzly installation. I add an image with metadata [see the code] using [Openstack python API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-openstack-pythonapis/).

I use  *glance.images.create* and provide metadata by *properties* argument. Unfortunately, the created image has no metadata (properties). *image.get* prints *NONE*.

```
import keystoneclient.v2_0.client as ksclient
import glanceclient

keystone = ksclient.Client(auth_url=credentials['auth-url'], username=credentials['username'],
                       password=credentials['password'], tenant_name=credentials['tenant'])

glance_endpoint = keystone.service_catalog.url_for(service_type='image',
                                                   endpoint_type='publicURL')

glance = glanceclient.Client('1',glance_endpoint, token=keystone.auth_token)
image_name="test-cirros"
image_file="cirros.img"

with open( image_file ) as fimage:
            image = glance.images.create(name=image_name, is_public=True, disk_format="qcow2", container_format="bare", data=fimage, properties =  {"aaaa": "13", "'bbbbbb": "12"} )
            print image.get() // prints NONE
```

Is there other way of setting image metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom Properties != metadata, so the horizon does not display them and image.get returns empty hash.

To grab the metadata, I need to use nova client (API version 1.1 ---  *nova.images.get(image.id).metadata*):

```
 # ...
 from novaclient import client as novaclient

 # ...

 nova = novaclient.Client("1.1", auth_url=credentials['auth-url'], username=credentials['username'], api_key=credentials['password'], project_id=credentials['tenant'])

 # ...

 with open( image_file ) as fimage:
            image = glance.images.create(name=image_name, is_public=True, disk_format="qcow2", container_format="bare", data=fimage, properties =  {"aaaa": "13", "'bbbbbb": "12"} )

             print nova.images.get(image.id).metadata # prints the correct metadata
```